# Isotope item - make link clickable, not whole item

Tags: jquery, hyperlink, jquery-isotope

I have knocked up demo of an isotope layout from some code I have found.

Demo here: http://www.fastnetstaging.co.uk/playground/isotope-property.html

Each 'item' (div) is clickable.

Question: I want only the text to be clckable (i.e. prop1, prop2, etc), not the whole item div.

How would I achieve this by editing the html/ script?

HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
<script src="js/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.isotope.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="startekContainer" class="results">
  <div class="item"><a href="#">prop1<br /> <img src="images/img04.jpg" /></a></div>
  <div class="item"><a href="#">prop2<br /> <img src="images/img05.jpg" /></a></div>
  <div class="item"><a href="#">prop3<br /> <img src="images/img06.jpg" /></a></div>
  <div class="item"><a href="#">prop4<br /> <img src="images/img07.jpg" /></a></div>
  <div class="item"><a href="#">prop5<br /> <img src="images/img09.jpg" /></a></div>
  <div class="item"><a href="#">prop6<br /> <img src="images/img10.jpg" /></a></div>
  <div class="item"><a href="#">prop7<br /> <img src="images/img11.jpg" /></a></div>
  <div class="item"><a href="#">prop8<br /> <img src="images/img12.jpg" /></a></div>
  <div class="item"><a href="#">prop9<br /> <img src="images/img13.jpg" /></a></div>
  <div class="item"><a href="#">prop10<br /> <img src="images/img04.jpg" /></a></div>
  <div class="item"><a href="#">prop11<br /> <img src="images/img05.jpg" /></a></div>
  <div class="item"><a href="#">prop12<br /> <img src="images/img06.jpg" /></a></div>
  <div class="item"><a href="#">prop13<br /> <img src="images/img07.jpg" /></a></div>
  <div class="item"><a href="#">prop14<br /> <img src="images/img09.jpg" /></a></div>
  <div class="item"><a href="#">prop15<br /> <img src="images/img10.jpg" /></a></div>
  <div class="item"><a href="#">prop16<br /> <img src="images/img11.jpg" /></a></div>
  <div class="item"><a href="#">prop17<br /> <img src="images/img12.jpg" /></a></div>
  <div class="item"><a href="#">prop18<br /> <img src="images/img13.jpg" /></a></div>
  <div class="item"><a href="#">prop19<br /> <img src="images/img04.jpg" /></a></div>
  <div class="item"><a href="#">prop20<br /> <img src="images/img05.jpg" /></a></div>
  <div class="item"><a href="#">prop21<br /> <img src="images/img06.jpg" /></a></div>
  <div class="item"><a href="#">prop22<br /> <img src="images/img07.jpg" /></a></div>
  <div class="item"><a href="#">prop23<br /> <img src="images/img09.jpg" /></a></div>
  <div class="item"><a href="#">prop24<br /> <img src="images/img10.jpg" /></a></div>
  <div class="item"><a href="#">prop25<br /> <img src="images/img11.jpg" /></a></div>
  <div class="item"><a href="#">prop26<br /> <img src="images/img12.jpg" /></a></div>
  <div class="item"><a href="#">prop27<br /> <img src="images/img13.jpg" /></a></div>
  <div class="item"><a href="#">prop28<br /> <img src="images/img04.jpg" /></a></div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(window).load(function(){
    $(function(){


      var $container = $('#startekContainer'),
          $items = $('.item');

      $container.isotope({
        itemSelector: '.item',
        masonry: {
          columnWidth: 60
        },
        getSortData : {
          selected : function( $item ){
            // sort by selected first, then by original order
            return ($item.hasClass('selected') ? -1000 : 0 ) + $item.index();
          }
        },
        sortBy : 'selected'
      })

      $items.click(function(){
        var $this = $(this);
        // don't proceed if already selected
        var $previousSelected = $('.selected');
        if ( !$this.hasClass('selected') ) {
          $this.addClass('selected');
        }

        $previousSelected.removeClass('selected');

        // update sortData for new items size
        $container
          .isotope( 'updateSortData', $this )
          .isotope( 'updateSortData', $previousSelected )
          .isotope();

      });

    });
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
body {
    font-family: Arial;
}

#startekContainer {
    max-width: 1170px;
}

.item {
  width: 270px;
  height: auto;
  background: orange;
  margin: 5px;
  float: left;
}

.item.selected {
  width: 1060px;
  height: 400px;
  background: yellow;
  clear: both;
}

img {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}

a {
  color: #000;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 20px;
}

.isotope-item {
  z-index: 2;
}

.isotope-hidden.isotope-item {
  pointer-events: none;
  z-index: 1;
}

.isotope,
.isotope .isotope-item {
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.8s;
     -moz-transition-duration: 0.8s;
          transition-duration: 0.8s;
}

.isotope {
  -webkit-transition-property: height, width;
     -moz-transition-property: height, width;
          transition-property: height, width;
}

.isotope .isotope-item {
  -webkit-transition-property: -webkit-transform, opacity;
     -moz-transition-property:    -moz-transform, opacity;
          transition-property:         transform, opacity;
}

.isotope.no-transition,
.isotope.no-transition .isotope-item,
.isotope .isotope-item.no-transition {
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0s;
     -moz-transition-duration: 0s;
          transition-duration: 0s;
}
```

Here is a jsfiddle showing my issue http://jsfiddle.net/philiplocke/h88L1nd2/
If anyone wants to play/edit it...

Comment: Maybe I am missing something, but should it work just taking out the '<img>' tag from inside the '<a>' tag?

Comment: No... as it's the whole <div class="item"> that is clickable. I have tried <div class="item"><a href="#" class=""bla">prop1</a><br /> <img src="images/img04.jpg" /></div> and still the same. It's to do with the jquery I think.

Comment: here is a jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/philiplocke/h88L1nd2/ with the links in a different location as you suggested - not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just made a few tweaks:

`First:`

```
$items = $('.item a');
```

`Second:`

```
$items.click(function(){
    var $this = $(this).parent();
```

#### Working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/robertrozas/8t6ejaqq/

#### UPDATE: Working on class `bla` : http://jsfiddle.net/robertrozas/comzv3q4/3/

#### UPDATE 2: http://jsfiddle.net/robertrozas/comzv3q4/7/

Comment: Very cool... thanks... How can I change that to be a specific link class, not all links. i.e. <a href="#" class=""bla"> - as you can see my jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/philiplocke/comzv3q4/

Comment: Post a question about that topic and i should help you, no problem.

Comment: In my jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/philiplocke/comzv3q4/ how do I change $items = $('.item a'); to be on the specific link class. As I may have several other links in the item, one going off to another page for example.

Comment: I only want links with the class="bla" to work - no other links - jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/philiplocke/comzv3q4/

Comment: Like i said before, that is a completely different question...this time i'm going to help you, but in the near future just post one question at a time, ok...just wait for the update...cheers

Comment: Hi Robert - I have updated it here http://jsfiddle.net/philiplocke/comzv3q4/6/ with more links with different classes in that item div. You see, I may have more links in the item div, but only the link with the class="bla" should work. Apologies if I didn't explain properly.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add the following before the call "$items.click":

```
        $('.item img').css('cursor', 'default').click(function(e) {
            e.stopPropagation();
        });
        $items.click(function(){
```

bye

Comment: mmm... no, not working. I just want the text to be clickable.